# same source code - different browsers - jQuery plugin works in Firefox and Chrome, not in IE 9

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

Please visit this location:

http://stark.test.campuswebstore.mobi/CreateNewUser.aspx

and create a username of "aaa" and then click "Check Availability" button to the right of the textbox.

In Firefox and Chrome you should have a modal popup appear that says the username is not available.

In IE - the same dialog is in the lower left corner and it is just the text ... no styling and the position is off (should be screen center).

Tom

Comment: What are you trying to answer? It's a well known problem that IE does not meet specifications that other browsers do. We are not your testers.

Comment: He is asking about what specifically is IE not being compliant about and how to hack around it. I would normally say "screw IE" though. My suggestion is you instead display a warning saying IE is not supported and might present "issues".

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem I think:
ln. 91

```
    document.CS_StaticURL = "http://cmsprod.uis.kent.edu/";
document.CS_DynamicURL = "http://cmsprod.uis.kent.edu/";
 // -->

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="FVw1W1OPIe7mlesI8YCQhzU7ptUjlDaXS11Cp0zB2UY" />

</script>
```

While Chrom & FF might correct your placing of the meta tag. IE doesn't like it and cannot execute your script any further.

Comment: Well, what's the answer? I commend you on finding the issue, but how should one go about fixing it?

Comment: Well, I don't have your source code to change it but please remove that meta tag to your head tag ^^